# Laravel custom each directive

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade, directive

I am working on a custom package for one of my projects and came up with an idea to create a custom blade directive for the elements that I want to loop through.

I made a sample code that does not work:

```
// WIRES
    \Blade::directive('startWire', function($params) {
        $wires = [
            0 => [
                'name' => 'test1',
                'image' => 'http://image.jpg'
            ],
        ];
        return "<?php foreach($wires as $wire): ?>";
    });

    \Blade::directive('endWire', function() {
        return "<?php endforeach; ?> ";
    });
```

And in the Blade file I wan to use it like:

```
@startWire()

@endWire
```

But I got the following error:

> Array to string conversion

I tried to escape the string but nothin seems to be a good choice. Shall I extend the default Blade @foreach directive or how it supposed to work?

Thank you for your answers!

Gábor

Comment: Your `$wire` will be an array. If you're going to `echo $wire`, you'll get `array to string conversion`. If you extend default `@foreach` statement, then you might break everything that relies on it. I see no actual reason why you need an additional directive that does a simple loop over an array, you have `@foreach` for that, but then again - it's not my code, so who am I to judge :)

Comment: Actually it will be a package where for example I can loop through blog posts to make the frontend developers life a bit easier. :) For example `@posts  @postTitle  @endposts` or something like this.

Comment: If you think you can simplify iterating over an array with a more complex interface that makes people learn your directives, then I really wish you the best of luck :) maybe I'm old and silly, but I see nothing simple in learning a number of new directives instead of using 1 directive. But, that's just me :) Please refer to my first comment to track your error, it should be simple enough to catch it. You're using an array of arrays, but you're iterating only once.

Comment: Sorry for the late answer but I was out of office last week, thank you for your aswer! :)